# How do take a vector and copy paste it in to my R code as if I typed it out manually?

Tags: r, csv, sample

for example

sample.int(100,6) might create a vector 7,43,42,97,1,23

I want to take whatever vector it creates and put it in my R script so it never changes.

how do I take this vector and paste it in to an R script so it looks like c(7,43,42,97,1,23)?

What I'm doing now is writing the sample.int vector to a csv, opening the csv in notepad which shows all the numbers neatly separated by a comma and then copy/pasting it back in to my R script.

Comment: if you're using `sample`, you can use `set.seed` to get the same results every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same function that is recommended when you need to provide data for an SO reprex:

```r
dput(sample.int(100,6))
#> c(1L, 66L, 45L, 22L, 33L, 61L)
```

Comment: Wow that is perfect!

Comment: I appreciate it. The agreed way to say "thanks" in SO is to accept and/or upvote an answer this way others know that an answer was helpful without reading comments.

Comment: Done. It says I don't have enough reputation to upvote, I figured I didn't have enough rep to accept an answer either.